# How does Heroes of Might & Magic 3 choose which music to play at the beginning of a battle?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

There are eight different short audio clips played at the beginning of every battle in HoMM III. The corresponding file names are battle0{0..7}.wav (contained in one of the .snd archives).

How does the game choose which one to play: is it random, or does it depend on the battle terrain / other factors?

Comment: I plated HoMM3 A LOT, as other HoMM games, but never was able to discover any specific pattern. My bet is that they are picked in a fully random manner.

Comment: I find it doesn't matter - they're all in the key of awesome! :-)

Comment: @acalypso, Seems like reverse engineering the code is the only way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's completely random from what I remember.

Comment: Please cite some sources.